# How to remove the alphanumeric characters from a list and split them in the result?

Tags: python-3.x, list, split, alphanumeric

```
'''def tokenize(s):
    string = s.lower().split()
    getVals = list([val for val in s if val.isalnum()])
    result = "".join(getVals) 
    print (result)'''
```

tokenize('AKKK@eastern B!@#est!')

Im trying for the output of  ('akkkeastern', 'best')

but my output for the above code is - AKKKeasternBest
what are the changes I should be making

Comment: replace `s` in `getVals` by `string` and use two list comprehensions (since strings is a list of strings). Use: `[''.join([val for val in word if val.isalnum()]) for word in string]`. (this also includes the `"".join(getVals)`).

Comment: thank you.. can u be a bit more specific about the two list comprehensions part.

Comment: As an answer it might be easier to read, but what you do is first loop over all groups from `s.lower().split()`, (which are `["akkk@eastern", "b!@#est!"]`, where `"akkk@eastern"` is the first word, etc...) using  `for word in string`. Then in the inner part you check every character for being alpha numeric (`[val for val in word if val.isalnum()]`).  The final part `''.join([...])` is the same as your line `result = "".join(getVals)`, but now performed on every word.

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension is a good way to filter elements out of a sequence like a string.  In the example below, the list comprehension is used to build a list of characters (characters are also strings in Python) that are either alphanumeric or a space - we are keeping the space around to use later to split the list.  After the filtered list is created, what's left to do is make a string out of it using `join` and last but not least use `split` to break it in two at the space.

Example:

```
string = 'AKKK@eastern B!@#est!'

# Removes non-alpha chars, but preserves space
filtered = [
    char.lower()
    for char in string
    if char.isalnum() or char == " "
]

# String-ifies filtered list, and splits on space
result = "".join(filtered).split()
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['akkkeastern', 'best']
```